# Function adjustments to read from a cleaned txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have this code I'm working with below, however my dataset is a txt file with multiple rows of the "t" example.
How can I adjust this code snippet to read that file?

```
t = "ABC//DEF//64/G//HI/55/123/JK2L"

k = [[]] # start with empty inner list
for l in t:
    if l == "/":
        k.append([]) # add new inner list
    else:
        k[-1].append(l) # add to last inner list

# fix lists to strings or empty string
for i,v in enumerate(k):
    v = ''.join(v)  # combine inner list to string
    
    # store empty if string is all numbers, else store v
    k[i] = "" if v.isdigit() else v

print (k)
print ([o for o in k if o]) # remove empty values from list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with list comprehension:

```
output = [[word for word in line.split("/") if not word.isnumeric() and word.strip()] for line in open("temp.txt").read().splitlines()]

>>> output
[['ABC', 'DEF', 'G', 'HI', 'JK2L'], ['MNO', 'PQ7R', 'S', 'TU', 'V8WX']]
```

###### temp.txt:

```
ABC//DEF//64/G//HI/55/123/JK2L
MNO//PQ7R//93/S//TU/96/893/V8WX
```